# Round off number to the nearest Highest number from array besides last one

Tags: javascript

```js
var counts = [2, 33, 61, 92, 125, 153, 184, 215, 245, 278, 306, 335, 365],
  goal = 35;

let min = Math.min(...counts.filter(num => num >= goal));

console.log(min)
```

This works **but** in case `goal=400`, I will get **365** back as it's the last number in the array

Comment: Why `.filter()` + `Math.min()`? `.find()` does that all in one.

Comment: _"...but in case goal=400 I will get 365..."_ - No, you would get `Infinity` because that's what `Math.min(...[])` would return.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the wanted value or take the value at last index.

```js
const
    find = (array, value) => array.find((v, i, { length }) =>
        v >= value || i + 1 === length
    ),
    counts = [2, 33, 61, 92, 125, 153, 184, 215, 245, 278, 306, 335, 365];

console.log(find(counts, 35));
console.log(find(counts, 400));
```

A slightly different approach by taking the last item, if `undefined`.

```js
const
    find = (array, value) => array.find(v => v >= value) ?? array.at(-1),
    counts = [2, 33, 61, 92, 125, 153, 184, 215, 245, 278, 306, 335, 365];

console.log(find(counts, 35));
console.log(find(counts, 400));
```

Comment: what happens if goal=400?

Comment: what do you want in this case?

Comment: the result will be 365

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the array is sorted?

Comment: @CameronFord, yes, the data looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the smallest number above the goal, or the largest number in counts if there are no numbers above the goal

```
const counts = [2,33,61,92,125,153,184,215,245,278,306,335,365]
goal = 35;
const above_goal = counts.filter(num => num >= goal)
  
const min = above_goal.length === 0 ? Math.max(counts) : Math.min(above__goal)
  
console.log(min)
```